# set variables in procedure level to be used in public? "object required error"

Tags: excel, vba

## MODULE01

```
Option Explicit
Public target_des As Range, target_tot As Range
Private Sub get_columns_letters()
'
'
' alot of lines which is irrelevant

' to set the target column as the total column

If Not tot_tot_col_U Is Nothing Then
    target_tot = tot_tot_col_U
ElseIf Not tot_totalcell Is Nothing Then
    target_tot = tot_totalcell
Else
    target_tot = ActiveSheet.Range("U")
End If
' to set the target column as description col
If Not description_col_U Is Nothing Then
    target_des = description_col_U
ElseIf Not Descell Is Nothing Then
    target_des = Descell
Else
    target_des = ActiveSheet.Range("B")
End If

End Sub
```

## MODULE02

```
Private Sub Organize_other()

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Sheets("Project cost proposal").Activate
        Dim fstcell As Range
        Dim lstcell As Range
        Set fstcell = Cells(1, 1)
        Set lstcell = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count)
        Range(fstcell, lstcell).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Dim Firstrow As Long
        Dim lastrow As Long
        Dim Lrow As Long
        Dim CalcMode As Long
        Dim ViewMode As Long

        With Sheets("Project cost proposal")
            .Select
            ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
            ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
            .DisplayPageBreaks = False

            Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
            lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
            For Lrow = lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
                Select Case Lrow
                    Case 1, 2, 3
                    Case Else

                    With .Cells(Lrow, target_tot.Column) ' HERE IS MY PROBLEM
                        If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                            If .Value = "0" Or .Value = "" Then 
                               .EntireRow.Delete
                        End If

                    End With
                End Select
            Next Lrow
            End With

            ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode

            ' RUN OTHER MACROS TO COMPLETE ORGANIZING SHEET
            Range("A1").Select
            Application.Run "module07.AssignUnique"
            Application.Run "module11.assign_formula_to_projectoverall"

            ' then adjust column and rows
            Worksheets("project cost proposal").Activate

            With Application

                ' to adjust cell size and auto fit
                Cells.Select
                Selection.Rows.AutoFit
                Selection.UnMerge

                Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count)).Select
                Selection.WrapText = False
                Selection.Rows.AutoFit
            End With
End Sub
```

all the variables used to identify the target_tot is defined in module 1, so when i use debug in module 1 it show the right address for target_tot, but in the second module seems like it go back to nothing or unidentified anymore.
some of the public declaration that were used to make the program find which column to target "target_tot" is :

```
Public description_col As String, unitcost_col As String, total_idiqpricing_col As String, mat_unit_cost_col As String

Public mat_qty_col As String

Public man_hours_col As String, rate_per_hour_col As String, eq_hours_col As String, eq_rate_per_hour_col As String

Public sub_cost_col As String, L_tot_col As String, eq_tot_col As String, mat_tot_col As String, tot_tot_col As String

Public description_col_U As Range ' for description column user selected

Public tot_tot_col_U As Range

Public Descell As Variant, tot_totalcell As Variant
```

It always gives me error object required in the second module target_tot is nothing can any one help?

Comment: Module1: You haven't used the Set keyword. It's repeatedly missing e.g.Set target_tot = tot_tot_col_U

Comment: You need module 1 to set the values for module 2

Comment: with "Set" its invalid qualifier error, what qualifier you think i should use? i tried .value

Comment: We have no idea what the variable `tot_tot_col_U ` is or what it represents. It should be an object of some sort, i.e. `Range`, `ListObject`, etc. In order to assign your public objects properly you must use `Set target_tot = tot_tot_col_U`. But we can't tell what qualifier to use because you have not shared the definition of `tot_tot_col_U`

Comment: Declare your variables on separate lines (much easier to debug) and ensure option explicit is at top. Step through code with F8 and you will soon get flagging of type mismatches.